# Nested loop through databases in loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 the same databases

```
('User1','User2','User3','User4')
```

And a loop doing what it supposed to do:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @getid CURSOR

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
SELECT [custom_data] FROM [User1].[usr].[table] where [custom_data] like '%:true%' or [custom_data] like '%:false%'

OPEN @getid
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO @json
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.field','value')
FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @json
END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

My question is: How do I iterate through databases? I have tried to nest the loop containing variable with database name and then execute query in this way:

First I:

```
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sysdatabases WHERE name IN ('User1','User2','User3','User4')
```

as described in many examples and after that I wanted to concat db name into query and execue it like that:

```
DECLARE @dbname varchar(50)
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sysdatabases 
WHERE name IN ('User1','User2','User3','User4')
OPEN C
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
EXEC('DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @getid CURSOR; SET @getid = CURSOR FOR SELECT [custom_data] FROM '+@dbName+'.[usr].[transactions]

OPEN @getid;
FETCH NEXT;
FROM @getid INTO @json;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0;
BEGIN;
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@json, ''$.Field'',''Value'');

FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @json
END
CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid')
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @dbname
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```

but it finishes loop with no errors with massage

> Commands completed successfully.

but it changes nothing. I would appreciate your assistance

Comment: Do sure why you are making this harder on your self that it has to `SELECT * FROM User1.t UNION ALL SELECT * FROM User2.t` ?

Comment: Oh man, the simplest solutions are the best:) Really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can execute a statement within the context of a specific database in ad-hoc sql your have to execute a USE  statement like this (don't omit the GO instruction otherwise it won't work):

```
SET @sql = 'USE '+@dbname+';'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'GO'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'SELECT DB_NAME();'
```

Also, don't forget to use a FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @dbname **before** your start your WHILE too otherwise your @dbname won't contain a usable value.